# YOLOv8 does not take torch tensor as input in python script

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, object-detection, yolo

I have a custom neural network where I want to use the output of a YOLO model run on the same input as part of my target. (E.g. number of objects in the image.)
For that I build my own class as follows:

```
class yolo_mask_model(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, weight_path = '/mypath/weights/best.pt'):
        super(yolo_mask_model, self).__init__()
        self.save_hyperparameters()
        self.pretrained_yolo = YOLO(weight_path)
        
    def forward(self, input):
        model_input = list(255 * np.transpose(input.cpu().numpy(),(0,2,3,1)))
        yolo_output = self.pretrained_yolo(model_input, stream=False)
        ... some more code
```

However I do find the step to go from `torch.tensor` to a list of numpy arrays very inefficient since it requires shifting data from my gpu to the cpu and back.

When I just plug in the tensor directly I receive the following errormessage:

`Exception has occurred: AssertionError Expected PIL/np.ndarray image type, but got <class 'torch.Tensor'>`

Is there any way around this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

The YOLO model performs some augmentation over the input images before the forward pass and so it expected a numpy array (or a list of image paths on disk). It uses cv2 to do the augmentation which cannot be performed on tensors. So you are forced to convert the tensors from the upstream model and convert in into numpy arrays before passing them to yolo. I do not say a way out of it. Reference: [Link](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/utils/augmentations.py#L140)